# Aggregation with MongoDB 3.6 and Morphia 1.3.2

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am trying to aggregate a MongoDB (3.6) using Morphia (1.3.2).

Currently it is a simple match and unwind to understand Morphia's API.

The problem that I am facing however is related to MongoDB 3.6:

---

Changed in version 3.4: MongoDB 3.6 removes the use of aggregate command without the cursor option unless the command includes the explain option. Unless you include the explain option, you must specify the cursor option.

---

This paragraph comes directly from the MongoDB documentation. [MongoDB Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate).

This means that a cursor is mandatory for the aggregate to work. However, I can't find a way to do this using Morphia. Therefore my aggregate does not work.

```
 AggregationPipeline data = aggregation.match(query).unwind("data");

 Iterator<LoraHourData> out = data.aggregate(Data.class);
```

The error that is produced using above code is as follows :

```
Command failed with error 9: The cursor option is required,     except for aggregate with the explain argument on server localhost:27017. The full response is { ok : 0.0, errmsg: The cursor option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument&quot;, code : 9, codeName : FailedToParse }
```

Comment: Can't you do something like `AggregationOptions opts = builder().outputMode(OutputMode.CURSOR).build();` and then `data.aggregate(Data.class, opts);`

Comment: @NeilLunn This works, except it is noted in the documentation as deprecated... I suppose the Morphia library needs some updating!

Comment: I believe 1.4 is in the works. Possibly needs volunteers!

Comment: @KevinVanDenBroek did you get a solution for this. I am stuck at the very same problem, today - after a year and a half.. :)